# How share users between containers?

Tags: docker

How share users between containers? I can create volume and mount it in /etc/ container directory, but it will hide another files/directories. Is exist any smarter idea to achieve goal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create common user between container, but you should define the user in your Dockerfile and pass the user name from the build args.

```
FROM alpine
ARG USER=default
ENV USER=${USER}
RUN echo ${USER} 
RUN addgroup -S ${USER}group && adduser -S $USER -G ${USER}group
USER $USER
```

So pass the host user at build time or any other name.

```
docker build --build-arg USER=$USER -t mycommon_user .
```

So if you check the user

```
docker run mycommon_user ash -c "whoami"
```

So any container that is launch from this dockerfile they will all have same user as the host user.